# ionic Cannot find module 'firebase/app' even if it is installed

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, angularfire2

I've cloned a working Ionic project from github and installed all the modules needed, also using `npm install @firebase/app`, but when running Ionic serve an error page is shown saying `Cannot find module 'firebase/app'`. When I installed firebase/app, it showed me this in the shell:

[image]

I guess there's a problem with the angularfire2 version that causes me the other problem? Which version should I use and how can I downgrade/upgrade that? To install angularfire2 I've simply run `npm install angularfire2`.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "progettoEM",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "4.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
"@angular/http": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
"@firebase/app": "^0.1.5",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
"@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"graphhopper-js-api-client": "^0.9.0-3",
"ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
"ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"leaflet": "^1.2.0",
"rxjs": "5.4.3",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
"ionic": "3.13.1",
"typescript": "2.3.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please include error messages as (formatted) text, not screenshots.

Comment: Got no formatted text anymore because I've give it some other tries. Sorry.

Comment: Instead of re-adding packages, have you tried `npm update` which should use `package.json` to install (or update) any required packages?

Comment: yes, but it gives me the same errors